# MarkLogic on MacOS with M1 chip

Tags: marklogic, apple-m1, marklogic-10

[As per the documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/installation/procedures#id_28962), MarkLogic will not work on Apple laptops with an M1 chip.

> The Apple M1 chip is not supported.

Is there any workaround and if there is a plan for any future M1 support?

Comment: This sounds like a better question to ask them, rather than here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated in the documentation, it M1 is not currently supported.

[AWS Gratiton](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/graviton/) is also ARM processor architecture and not currently supported.

It is possible to configure and run with Rosetta2 emulation software, though your milage may vary:
https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/marklogic-server-on-macos-rosetta2---apple-silicon-m1--mx

Market and customer demands will influence capabilities and priorities, so it would be best to contact MarkLogic directly and let them know that you are interested in M1 support.